# Prevent Duplicates in Rest API

Tags: vb.net, rest, asp.net-apicontroller

We have an API endpoint which accepts people.

During the call we check to ensure that the person PIN has not already been used, if so we reject the request with a 422 input error.

Recently a client complained about a duplicate PIN and we found that the API endpoint was being triggered by two different REST calls with duplicated PINs but not a duplicate body.

i.e.
`{First Name: John, Last Name: Doe, PIN: 722}`
`{First Name: Jane, Last Name: Doe, PIN: 722}`

As both come in within milliseconds of each other when the test is performed on the second record for the duplicate PIN it returns false as the first record has not yet been inserted into the DB and as a result continues to process the second record.

We have looked into a few options, such as unique constraints on the DB which do work but would require huge amounts of rework to bubble the error up to the REST API response. A huge risk on a thriving production APP.

There are around 5-6 different API calls that can modify the PIN collection in one guise or another and around 20-30 different APIs where this sort of problem exists (unique emails, unique item name etc) so I am not sure we can maintain lists for quick access.

Aside from the DB constraints are there any other options available to us that would be simpler to implement?  Perhaps some obscure attribute on the .NET APIController class.

In my head at least I would like a request to be made, and subsequent requests to be queued. I am aware we can simply store the payload for processing later however on  the basis the APIs are already being consumed this doesn't seem to be an option the queue would have to block the response.

Trying to Google this has been far from successful as everything assumes I am trying to decline duplicate complete bodies.

Comment: Since you already see locking as a possible solution maybe distributed locking may help? RedLock.net for instance? You could lock related resources every time PIN is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

If you're basing the check on whether the PIN exists in the db, in theory you could have tens or hundreds of potential duplicates coming in on the REST API, all assuming the PIN is ok as the database is slow to say whether a PIN exists.

If you think of it as a pipeline:

> client -> API -> PIN check from db -> ok -> insert in db

the `PIN check from db` is a bottleneck as it will most likely be slower than incoming REST calls. As you say, the solution is to enforce the uniqueness at the database level but if that's not practical, you could use a 'gateway' check instead. Basically a PIN cache that's fast to update/query and PINs are added to it once the request has been accepted for processing and before they're written to the database. So the pipeline becomes:

> client -> API -> PIN check from cache -> ok -> write PIN to cache ->
>   insert in db

and the second request would end up as:

> client -> API -> PIN check from cache -> exists -> fail

so the cache is keeping up with the requests, allowing the more leisurely database operations to continue with known clean data. You'd have to build the cache (from PINs in the database) on every service restart and only allow API calls once the cache is ready if it's a memory cache. Or you could use a disk cache. The downside is it duplicates all the PINs in your database but it's a compromise that lets you keep up with checking PINs in API calls.

Comment: Unfortunatley there are so many different APIs that can modify PINs (PostPeople, PutPerson, ChangePIN etc) that it would become unmanagable very quickly. On top of this the site is multitenanted so while PIN 500 might be taken for one client it isn't for another. In my head at least I was hoping for a solution where subsequent calls to the API were locked until the first responded. I am aware of the queing option however fear this is too big of a change for those consuming our API, I would prefer if it was blocked. Apologies will update question to include these things.